# Use PGP key with MS Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, gnupg, pgp

How do I use a PGP/GNUPG key to encrypt/decrypt emails sent using MS Outlook 2010?

I understand the basics of PGP/GNUPG, and have a public/private key setup.  I just want to know how to use this with Outlook 2010.  Do I have to use some sort of Outlook pluggin which makes use of the keys, or do I need to encrypt the emails outside of Outlook and then copy and paste the encrypted text and images into Outlook later?

Answer (score 1):

There's a free software project [GPG4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org/index.html), which contains among GnuPG, some key management user interface and other tools an **Outlook plugin named *GpgOL***. It offers native Outlook support for all versions from 2003 to 2013, including 2010 (as most Outlook Plugins, 32 bit only – but most Office installations will bit 32 bit anyway).

Originally sponsored by the German government, development is today continued by a community around it.